# XPC connection interrupted in Xcode 8 for iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10, xcode8

I recently updated to Xcode 8 and upgraded my iPhone to iOS 10. I have developed and released an iOS app that had worked perfectly fine on the latest version of iOS 9 and Xcode 7.3.

Upon trying to go through the process of updated the app for iOS 10 support, I am getting the most ridiculously strange error that has left me baffled.

I have done all the syntax corrections automatically through Xcode, and now my app builds properly. It even runs fine at first.

In Xcode, I get the following messages:

XPC Connection Interrupted.
Terminating since there is no system app.

I have Flurry analytics integrated in my app by the way, not sure if thats an issue.

How can I fix this issue? My searches for XPC connections do not seem to return problems similar to mine. I do not even have a clue what an XPC connection is, so why is this in my app anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem here,delete "@synchronized (self){}",it work well.

```
@synchronized (self)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

    }); 
}
```